# Best practices to remove columns from CSV that is saved as ArrayList

Tags: java, csv, arraylist

I have to read in some CSV files that then get split up and parsed into an ArrayList. So every entry of the ArrayList represents one field of the CSV. My problem now is, that I have to sometimes get rid of certain columns dynamically, based on the header. This means that if a header columns fulflills a certain condition it has to be deleted from the CSV. Sometimes there is more than one column in one CSV that could fulfill the condition.

So what I did as a first solution was first iterating over a separate ArrayList containing the headers and saving the indexes of those in need to be removed into another arraylist. Afterwards I iterated over the content Array with the indexes of the columns headers that need to get deleted and adding the row size to it in order to get the indexes of the entries that need to be deleted into another ArrayList. After that I iterated over the array holding the content and removing the content that has to be deleted, starting at the highest index of the list in order to keep the indexes in place while removing some of the content.

The problem with this solution is that it is not good when there is a large amount of entries in a CSV file. So I am wondering if there would be a better solution to this?

Comment: Don't use an ArrayList to store the CSV, or if you have no choice, convert it to a `Map`, where each KEY is a column and the value is an arrayList of the values for the column. Each of the values (array lists) are gonna be the same size, since they all come from the same "table". After that single pass work, proceed to remove all the Keys from the columns you don't want. Think `Map<String, List<String>` (or `Map<Column, List<Row>` if you prefer an easier to read version). The initial conversion is still `O(n)` but afterwards... very fast.

Comment: "It is not good when there is a large amount of entries" It's not that bad, at least for time complexity. But if you want your code to look more concise, you can use csv parsing libraries. (I'm not sure if they provides APIs to remove columns)